# Dll build success, but error execute when loading dll

Tags: c#, c++

I have built a dll file, and loading it with windows form writing in c#.
When I debugging with Visual Studio(2013 in win8) it ran success, then I moved debug folder to other computer with win7 and ran it then fail, it says 'Could not load file or assembly 'mydll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

I think it could be failed by choosing the wrong target computer in dll properties, so I change 'MachineX86' to 'MachineX64' and rebuild it, windows from's target platform also changed to x64, but it always failed.

I am new to build dll and loading it by myself, I don't know something missing when I build the dll file. If anyone can answer...

Comment: @mjwills Some confidential name in code that I cannot show...

Comment: I'd suggest reading the link I provided. We don't need **all** of the code. Just a [mcve] sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The error is _"Could not load file or assembly 'mydll.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."_ it could be that something your DLL depends on is not present on the target machine. Did you fish out all the contents of your project's bin folder. What kind of project is this? Have tried looking for the failure with _Process Monitor_?

Comment: You cannot move debug folder to another computer. Only release version could run on computer without Visual Studio since the debug C++ run time is not redistributable.

Comment: @Phil1970 But if I copy all project folder to win10 and rebuild it, it will run.

Comment: @Phil1970 You're right... I use release and build then work...

Answer (score 0):

also, using [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) may help in understanding which assembly is missing/can't be loaded